# Map values in a pandas series according to MultiIndex values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a `pd.Series` with a multiindex.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the Series
data = {
    ("long_only", "Security_1"): -1,
    ("long_only", "Security_3"): 1,
    ("long_only", "Security_5"): 1,
    ("short_only", "Security_2"): -1,
    ("short_only", "Security_4"): 1,
    ("both", "Security_1"): -2,
    ("both", "Security_2"): -1,
    ("both", "Security_4"): 1,
}

signals = pd.Series(data, dtype="int8")
signals.index = signals.index.set_names(["direction", "symbol"])

print(signals)

direction   symbol    
long_only   Security_1   -1
            Security_3    1
            Security_5    1
short_only  Security_2   -1
            Security_4    1
both        Security_1   -2
            Security_2   -1
            Security_4    1
dtype: int8
```

Now I would like to transform the integer values into strings according to the following `dict`:

```
# Define the mapping dictionary
trade_state_dict = {
    "long_only": {
        -1: "long -> flat",
        1: "flat -> long",
    },
    "short_only": {
        -1: "flat -> short",
        1: "short -> flat",
    },
    "both": {
        -2: "long -> short",
        -1: "long -> flat",
        1: "flat -> long",
        2: "short -> long",
    },
}
```

I need to use the "direction" level for finding the inner dictionary in `trade_state_dict`.

The expected result should look like this:

```
direction   symbol    
long_only   Security_1   "long -> flat"
            Security_3   "flat -> long"
            Security_5   "flat -> long"
short_only  Security_2   "flat -> short"
            Security_4   "short -> flat"
both        Security_1   "long -> short"
            Security_2   "long -> flat"
            Security_4   "flat -> long"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, transform the series into a pd.DataFrame.

```
signals = pd.DataFrame(signals, columns=['target']).reset_index()
print(signals)
```

```
    direction      symbol  target
0   long_only  Security_1      -1
1   long_only  Security_3       1
2   long_only  Security_5       1
3  short_only  Security_2      -1
4  short_only  Security_4       1
5        both  Security_1      -2
6        both  Security_2      -1
7        both  Security_4       1
```

Next, transform the integer values into strings.

```
signals['target'] = signals.apply(lambda x: trade_state_dict[x['direction']][x['target']], axis=1)
print(signals)
```

```
    direction      symbol         target
0   long_only  Security_1   long -> flat
1   long_only  Security_3   flat -> long
2   long_only  Security_5   flat -> long
3  short_only  Security_2  flat -> short
4  short_only  Security_4  short -> flat
5        both  Security_1  long -> short
6        both  Security_2   long -> flat
7        both  Security_4   flat -> long
```

Final, generate new `signals`.

```
signals = signals.groupby(['direction', 'symbol']).apply(lambda x: x['target'])
print(signals)
```

```
direction   symbol       
both        Security_1  5    long -> short
            Security_2  6     long -> flat
            Security_4  7     flat -> long
long_only   Security_1  0     long -> flat
            Security_3  1     flat -> long
            Security_5  2     flat -> long
short_only  Security_2  3    flat -> short
            Security_4  4    short -> flat
Name: target, dtype: object
```

Comment: I see what you are doing. And it is working as expected. However, I was hoping for a more consice solution. Maybe something like using ``map`` in concunction with a lambda function. Maybe it's easier to transform the series into a ``pd.DataFrame`` and reset the index before doing the transformation?

Comment: @Andi : 
I have updated the code. Does it meet your requirements.

Comment: Great, I think this is more intuitive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a dataframe from `trade_state_dict` and merge back to signals:

```py
contents = []
for key, value in trade_state_dict.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        contents.append((key, k, v))
contents = pd.DataFrame(contents, columns=['direction', 'int', 'target'])
(contents
.merge(signals
      .rename('int')
      .reset_index('symbol'), on = ['direction', 'int']
     )
.drop(columns='int')
.set_index(['direction', 'symbol'])
)

                              target
direction  symbol                   
long_only  Security_1   long -> flat
           Security_3   flat -> long
           Security_5   flat -> long
short_only Security_2  flat -> short
           Security_4  short -> flat
both       Security_1  long -> short
           Security_2   long -> flat
           Security_4   flat -> long
```